# Is it possible to limit max entries per minute for a text input in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, security

I'm about to finish my website that I wrote myself in HTML and I was wondering how can I make it secure.
I have limited the max length of the search bar and disabled special characters so far.
Is it possible to limit max entries per minute for a text input?
If anyone has any other suggestions on how can I make the website secure please tell me!
Thanks!

Comment: How does limiting input into a search bar make your application more secure? You should assume all user input is insecure and sanatize it regardless.

Comment: To your question: yes it is possible with JavaScript...

Comment: @Dominik  OP maybe means secure from DDOS attack type vectors, but this something that can't be handled client side anyway.  It's something he will need to handle server side..

Comment: Indeed. Not something you fix by limiting the search fields input ;)

Answer (score 0):

of course you have to decide how you will store the variable, because reloading the page will reset it, you can use a `cookie` or `localStorage`

```js
const out = document.querySelector('#output')
const txt = document.querySelector('#text')
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', enter, 'false');
const time = document.querySelector('#time')
let allowTime = new Date().getTime();

const diff = (end, start) => (end - start) / 1000

const lock = () => {
  const i = setInterval(()=> {
    const now = Date.now()
    const wait = diff(allowTime, now)
    if (wait <= 0) {
      time.textContent = 0;
      allowTime = now;
      clearInterval(i);
    } else {
      time.textContent = Math.floor(wait);
    } 
  },
  1000)
} 

function enter(){
  const now = Date.now();
  if (diff(allowTime, now ) <= 0)  {
    out.textContent += txt.value  + '\n';
    txt.value = '';
    allowTime = now + (1000 * 20) // <----- wait 20 seconds
    lock()
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="output">
</pre>
<p>wait: <span id="time">0</span> seconds</p>  
<input type="text" id="text">
<button id="btn">send</button>
```

Comment: Thanks man! How could i modify the code so that i would wait 1 second instead of 18?

Comment: here   allowTime = now + (1000 * 20) just multiply on seconds you want